# Setting common tax rate

Tags: tax

I need a common tax rate for all countries, cities and everything. Just common 25$ VAT for the whole world. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do that: import/export tax rates. create a file (!important has to be UTF-8 without BOM - otherwise didn't work for me) with the following contents:

"Code","Country","State","Zip/Post Code","Rate","Zip/Post is Range","Range From","Range To","swedish","english"
"VAT-AD","AD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AE","AE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AF","AF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AG","AG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AI","AI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AL","AL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AM","AM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AN","AN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AO","AO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AQ","AQ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AR","AR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AS","AS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AT","AT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AU","AU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AW","AW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AX","AX","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-AZ","AZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BA","BA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BB","BB","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BD","BD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BE","BE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BF","BF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BG","BG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BH","BH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BI","BI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BJ","BJ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BL","BL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BM","BM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BN","BN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BO","BO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BR","BR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BS","BS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BT","BT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BV","BV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BW","BW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BY","BY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-BZ","BZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CA","CA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CC","CC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CD","CD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CF","CF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CG","CG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CH","CH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CI","CI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CK","CK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CL","CL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CM","CM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CN","CN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CO","CO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CR","CR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CU","CU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CV","CV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CX","CX","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CY","CY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-CZ","CZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DE","DE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DJ","DJ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DK","DK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DM","DM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DO","DO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-DZ","DZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-EC","EC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-EE","EE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-EG","EG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-EH","EH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ER","ER","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ES","ES","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ET","ET","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FI","FI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FJ","FJ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FK","FK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FM","FM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FO","FO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-FR","FR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GA","GA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GB","GB","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GD","GD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GE","GE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GF","GF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GG","GG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GH","GH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GI","GI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GL","GL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GM","GM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GN","GN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GP","GP","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GQ","GQ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GR","GR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GS","GS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GT","GT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GU","GU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GW","GW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-GY","GY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HK","HK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HM","HM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HN","HN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HR","HR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HT","HT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-HU","HU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ID","ID","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IE","IE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IL","IL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IM","IM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IN","IN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IO","IO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IQ","IQ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IR","IR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IS","IS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-IT","IT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-JE","JE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-JM","JM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-JO","JO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-JP","JP","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KE","KE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KG","KG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KH","KH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KI","KI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KM","KM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KN","KN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KP","KP","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KR","KR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KW","KW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KY","KY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-KZ","KZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LA","LA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LB","LB","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LC","LC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LI","LI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LK","LK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LR","LR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LS","LS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LT","LT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LU","LU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LV","LV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-LY","LY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MA","MA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MC","MC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MD","MD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ME","ME","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MF","MF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MG","MG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MH","MH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MK","MK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ML","ML","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MM","MM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MN","MN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MO","MO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MP","MP","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MQ","MQ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MR","MR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MS","MS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MT","MT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MU","MU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MV","MV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MW","MW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MX","MX","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MY","MY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-MZ","MZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NA","NA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NC","NC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NE","NE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NF","NF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NG","NG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NI","NI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NL","NL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NO","NO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NP","NP","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NR","NR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NU","NU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-NZ","NZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-OM","OM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PA","PA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PE","PE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PF","PF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PG","PG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PH","PH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PK","PK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PL","PL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PM","PM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PN","PN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PR","PR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PS","PS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PT","PT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PW","PW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-PY","PY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-QA","QA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-RE","RE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-RO","RO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-RS","RS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-RU","RU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-RW","RW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SA","SA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SB","SB","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SC","SC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SD","SD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SG","SG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SH","SH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SI","SI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SJ","SJ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SK","SK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SL","SL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SM","SM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SN","SN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SO","SO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SR","SR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ST","ST","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SV","SV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SY","SY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-SZ","SZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TC","TC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TD","TD","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TF","TF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TG","TG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TH","TH","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TJ","TJ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TK","TK","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TL","TL","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TM","TM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TN","TN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TO","TO","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TR","TR","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TT","TT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TV","TV","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TW","TW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-TZ","TZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-UA","UA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-UG","UG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-UM","UM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-US","US","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-UY","UY","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-UZ","UZ","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VA","VA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VC","VC","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VE","VE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VG","VG","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VI","VI","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VN","VN","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-VU","VU","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-WF","WF","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-WS","WS","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-YE","YE","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-YT","YT","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ZA","ZA","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ZM","ZM","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""
"VAT-ZW","ZW","*","*","25.0000","","","","",""

Note that the last 2 values are for 2 languages I have. To see your format try to export first. 25.0000 is 25% tax

If anyone finds better solution, would be very thankful :)